# How do I connect to HTTP server with content type after requesting a specific file from directory?

Tags: http, networking, network-programming, webserver

I wrote a function that checks for file type (using Content Type) for HTTP server. However, I have this as global variable, but I blocked out the HTTP and content-type lines.

```
char * request_str; //= "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        //"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
```

The function that checks for file types as such as html, png, txt, etc. It has filename, filetype, and request_str as arguments. I'm hoping the request_str would return after reading the filename/filetype, but I guess it doesn't work.

```
void get_filetype(char *filename, char *filetype, char *request_str)
{
    if(strstr(filename, ".html"))
    {
        strcpy(filetype, "text/html");
        request_str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                    "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
        return request_str;
    }
else if(strstr(filename, ".gif"))
{
            strcpy(filetype, "image/gif");
    request_str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-type: image/gif; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
    return request_str;
}
else if(strstr(filename, ".png"))
    { 
       strcpy(filetype, "image/png");
    request_str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-type: image/png; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
    return request_str;
}
else if(strstr(filename, ".jpg"))
{
            strcpy(filetype, "image/jpg");
    request_str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-type: image/jpg; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
    return request_str;
}
else
{
    strcpy(filetype, "text/plain");
    request_str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
    return request_str;
    }
}
```

I have this function in the server request function when it attempts to connect to server. The problem I'm approaching is it wouldn't connect to the web server when I test it on my browser so I cannot see anything. Am I supposed to check the file type before attemtpting to connect to the server? Thank you guys in advance.

```
    while(1){
    file_offset += recv(client_fd,&client_buf[file_offset],4096,0);
    if(strstr(client_buf,"\r\n\r\n"))
      break;
  }


requested_file = parseRequest(client_buf);

  if(stat(filename, &for_filename) < 0)
  {
        clienterror(client_fd, filename, "404", "Not found", "Webserver couldn't find this file");
        return;
  }

  get_filetype(filename, file_type, request_str);
  send(client_fd,request_str,strlen(request_str),0);

  // take requested_file, add a . to beginning, open that file
  filename[0] = '.';
  strncpy(&filename[1],requested_file,4095);
  read_fd = open(filename,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I supposed to check the file type before attemtpting to connect to
>   the server?

First of all, unless you're doing it as an exercise, you should really use an HTTP client library instead of building request strings yourself.

Second, in HTTP, you can specify multiple accepted formats in a single request. Browsers use a list of default values which you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values). For instance, when Firefox doesn't know in advance the type of data it's supposed to request, it uses the string `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`. If it knows that it's a video, then it uses a different string `audio/webm, audio/ogg, audio/wav, audio/*;q=0.9, application/ogg;q=0.7, video/*;q=0.6; */*;q=0.5`. There are additional request string for other types such as images, and scripts.